# Set height of one element based on visibility of another

Tags: css

I have two divs. The top one is a menu and the bottom one is content.

The menu div have a fixed hight of 30 pixels, and the content div is set with calc(100% - 30px). As it is now I have to switch between a no-menu style and a menu style depending on if the menu is hidden or not. Easy-peasy - but...

Is it possible to reference the menu somehow in the content's style so calc is calculated either by the menu's visibility or its height.

Something like this:

```
#menu {
    height: 30px;
}

#content {
    height: calc(100% - #menu.height);
}
```

Or this:

```
#content:if #menu:visible {
    height: calc(100% - 30px);
}

#content:if #menu:hidden {
    height: calc(100% - 0px);
}
```

Comment: When the menu is hidden the element is still on the markup? How do you hide it? Can we see your actual markup structure?

Comment: I was "pseudocoding" it. I of course "display: none;" to hide it - or it wouldn't be right to change the height of the content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could apply a `hidden` class to the `#menu` and, assuming that your div are siblings, you may use the [general sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors) e.g.

**Css**

```
#menu { height: 30px; }
#menu.hidden { display: none; }

#content { height: calc(100% - 30px); }
#menu.hidden ~ #content { height: 100%; }
```

Comment: ... and if they aren’t siblings, then set the class on a common parent element, and use the descendant selector accordingly.

Comment: Yep, I've jut considered the OP description of his markup: *one on top and one on bottom* (in this specific example I don't think the content could be included as a child of the menu, but it's worth to mention)

Comment: Not saying put the content inside the menu, just use a common parent/ancestor element (such as f.e. body or html, which will be there in any case.)

Comment: They are siblings. Not sure exactly what's going on. Is the ~ some sort of if statement? Tried searching but google seem to ignore the ~ in the search.

Comment: @Espen there's a link in my answer on "general sibling selector"

Comment: I understand. Nifty little thing that ~ selector :-)

Answer (score 1):

Let's think differently: your content has a height of 100% minus the height of the nabar which means that **the content should take the remaining space left by the navbar in all the cases**.

This is pretty easy with flex as you simply need to set `flex:1` to the content. This will work when your navbar is hidden with `display:none` or `height:0` or even if you will simply change its height.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.container>nav {
  height: 30px;
  background: blue;
}

.container>div {
  flex: 1;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <nav>menu</nav>
  <div>content</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <nav style="display:none;">menu</nav>
  <div>content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Espen and your life you get easier ;) as we can read your question differently :"how to make the content to always fill the remaining space" and flex is the solution for this :) and this will work with *display:none* and even if you want to change the height

Comment: For reference I will most likely use flex for my specific situation, but I feel I have to select the other answer from @fcalderan as the answer as it solves the question more directly.

Comment: @Espen yes you are free to pick the answer you want :) but be aware that the other one work is some particular cases and cannot be a generic solution like the flex one ;)